# Integration of 1-form $\omega = f(xdx + ydy)$.

Tags: integration, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms

I am self-learning integration on manifolds, and I'm trying to find an answer to the following question.

For the manifold $M=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R} : (x,y) \neq (0,0) \}$, let $f: M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function and $\omega$ a smooth 1-form on $M$ given by

$\omega = f(xdx + ydy)$.

Let $C: [0,1] \rightarrow M$ be the curve given by

$C(t) = (cos (2\pi t), sin (2\pi t))$ for $0 \leq t \leq 1$.

I am trying to compute $\int_{C} \omega$ and then show that $dw=0$ if and only if $f=F(x^2+y^2)$ for some $F$.

I know that one would integrate a general $\omega = p(x,y)dx + q(x,y)dy$ along a curve C as follows:

$\int_{C} p(x,y)dx + q(x,y)dy = \int_0^1 (p(C(t))\frac{dC^x}{dt}+q(C(t))\frac{dC^y}{dt})$, where the latter is the pullback $C^\star \omega$.

However, I am still fairly new to this and I do not know how to approach this given this generic smooth function $f$. How is this done?

Comment: An $1$-form on $M$ has the form $\omega=P(x,y)dx+Q(x,y)dy$. For such an $\omega$ you can calculate $\int_C\omega$.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Yes, I had written the same above. I'm guessing this is obvious, but how does the function f appear in this form?

Comment: The notation $f(x dx, ydy)$ doesn't really make sense. If $f(x,y) = x^3 + 2y$, what is the meaning of $(x dx)^3 + 2(dy)$?

Comment: @JaneDoé Oh, there was indeed a typo - just added the correct plus sign.

Comment: So the only way I can parse this notation to make sense is that $\omega = (f(x,y)x) dx + (f(x,y)y) dy$, which lets you try to go ahead and integrate it

Comment: Your curve $C$ is the unit circle, while your differential form "intersects" your curve "orthogonally". What I mean is that the integral $\int_C\omega$ would have the same value as doing line integral of the vector field $F(x,y)=(f(x,y)x,f(x,y)y)$ along the curve $C$. The vector $(f(x,y)x,f(x,y)y)$ points radially from (or to) the origin, and must be orthogonal to the curve $C$. So you can attempt to prove the integral is zero.